# Saving the state of the button using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am doing one project in that i am struck in the middle.My problem is I have a button in my application when we click that i place a code to change the title of the button as below code

```
- (IBAction)syncOffClickedInRegisterUserScreen:(id)sender {
     if ([syncOnorOff.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Sync off"]) {
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 
    else{
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
  }
```

its working properly 
here is the code for application enter in to background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"1");
   registerUserScreen = [[RegisterUserScreen alloc]init];
    //if([[[registerUserScreen syncOnorOff]currentTitle]isEqualToString:@"Sync off"]){
    // NSLog(@"title is %@",[[registerUserScreen syncOnorOff]currentTitle]);
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
    NSDate *alertTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if(notifyAlarm){
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Sync Events";
        notifyAlarm.alertAction = @"Sync";
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
 }
```

my problem whenever the button having title Sync off in the userscreen  and enter into the background state it will execute the data which is in the background and if the button having with title Sync on in the userscreen and enter into the background state it doesnot execute the data which is in the background.how it is possible.If anybody knows please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but based on your title, here's how to save/read the title of your button to/from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//read
[defaults stringForKey:@"buttontitle"];
//write
[defaults setValue:[[registerUserScreen syncOnorOff]currentTitle] forKey:@"buttontitle"];
```